# QuickSort with 3 partitions

Tags: quicksort

Suppose we modified Quicksort to have three partitions instead of two. The left partition has values < pivot. The middle partition has values = pivot. The right partition has values > pivot. We then recurse on the left and right partitions. How much time will this 3-way partitioning take?

I see this in one of the interview questions, where answer was given as O(n). But for normal 1 parition quick sort it is O(nlogn).

Please help me understand why it O(n) ?

Comment: Agreed, but as it is one of the questions asked in interviews and they confirmed the answer as O(n), I am trying to figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

It's only O(n), when all values are the same. The first instance of partition will find all values == pivot (regardless of which value is chosen for the pivot), and since there are no values < or > pivot, no recursion occurs.

For normal data, time complexity remains average case O(n log(n)) or worst case O(n^2).